# Azure function : Application settings not working in production

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have the following value in my `local.settings.json`

[image: local.settings.json]

I am accessing the same in my startup class I added for my azure function as below

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        IConfiguration config;
        var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");


        config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .AddJsonFile($"local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();


        builder.Services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(IConfiguration), config));
        builder.Services.AddLogging();
        var executionContextOptions = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider()
        .GetService<IOptions<ExecutionContextOptions>>().Value;
        var currentDirectory = executionContextOptions.AppDirectory;



        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config);


        #region Serilog
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Information()
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Worker", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Host", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Error)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Function", LogEventLevel.Error)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("DurableTask", LogEventLevel.Error)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Azure.Storage.Blobs", LogEventLevel.Error)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Azure.Core", LogEventLevel.Error)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus", LogEventLevel.Error)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .WriteTo.AzureAnalytics(config["AZURE_WORKSPACE_ID"],///<-***issue here///
         config["AZURE_AUTHENTICATION_ID"])
        .Enrich.WithEnvironmentName()
        .CreateLogger();
        builder.Services.AddLogging(lb => lb.AddSerilog(Log.Logger, true));
        #endregion


        
    }
```

It works fine in local but in production even though I have the key `AZURE_WORKSPACE_ID` in application settings

[image]

I am getting the following error

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExternalStartupException : Error configuring services in an external startup class. ---> System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'workspaceId') at Serilog.LoggerConfigurationExtensions.AzureAnalytics(LoggerSinkConfiguration loggerConfiguration,String workspaceId,String authenticationId,String logName,LogEventLevel restrictedToMinimumLevel,Boolean storeTimestampInUtc,IFormatProvider formatProvider,Int32 logBufferSize,Int32 batchSize,AzureOfferingType azureOfferingType,LoggingLevelSwitch levelSwitch,Boolean flattenObject,String proxy)

`AZURE_WORKSPACE_ID` value is not being picked up

Comment: Try using `.SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)` for Azure and remove `.AddJsonFile($"local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)` for azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked for me both locally and in Azure, which is given below:

I have created a HTTP trigger function in `.NET 7 isolated`, which is getting a custom environment variable from `local.settings.json` in local and from `app settings` in Azure.

**`Program.cs`:**

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;  
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()  
.ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()  
.Build();

var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()  
.SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)  
.AddEnvironmentVariables()  
.AddJsonFile($"local.settings.json",optional: true, reloadOnChange:true)  
.Build();

host.Run();
```

**`Function1.cs`:**

```cs
using System.Net;  
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;  
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;  
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;  
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp5  
{  
public class Function1  
{  
private readonly ILogger _logger;  
private readonly IConfiguration _config;

public Function1(IConfiguration configuration, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)  
{  
_logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();  
_config = configuration;  
}

[Function("Function1")]  
public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)  
{  
_logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

string value = _config["Azure_custom_variable"];

var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);  
response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

response.WriteString($"Welcome to Azure Functions! \n\n {value}");

return response;  
}  
}  
}
```

#**Local Environment**
**`local.settings.json`**

```json
{  
"IsEncrypted": false,  
"Values": {  
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",  
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",  
"Azure_custom_variable": "Vivek, This is a HTTP trigger"  
}  
}
```

**`Output`:**

[image]

[image]

#**Azure**

[image]

**`Output`:**

[image]

Comment: Looking at your Program.cs code: you create a config with `ConfigurationBuilder`, but it does not go anywhere. Are you sure it takes any effect? I think, it will work exactly the same way if you remove this piece of code. The thing is: a function should pick up the config automatically from `local.settings.json` when running locally and from environment variables when deployed to cloud. If it does not happen, something else is wrong...